# How do I reduce noise in a normal map with Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture

I'll be straightforward: I want to create a normal map resembling this

[image: normal map]

from this texture:

[image: texture]

I've been at it for about an hour, and everything I've come up with has an absurd amount of noise. I don't expect it to be nearly as perfect as the first image, but something that doesn't look terrible would be nice. I'd prefer to use GIMP, though I do have a copy of Photoshop I can use.

Comment: My inclination is this isn't going to happen based on that image. The top image is generated from a texture pattern, not a photo.

Comment: @Scott But, is there any way to manipulate the bottom photo so that it would more closely resemble a pattern?

Comment: Not easily. You would need to *manually* go in and clean up the mortar areas of the photo.

Comment: @Scott I assume this wouldn't be a very good idea if I don't have experience in manual retouching?

Comment: Even for someone with experience, that's a job worth several hours of time.  You'd be better served by finding a rock texture pattern as shown in your top image. An hour of searching sure beats 3 days of manual retouching.

Comment: If I understand what you're saying correctly, I'd need to find a standalone bump map. The issue with that is, I need both the texture and the map in order to proceed.

Comment: Well it's going to take some manual editing then -- either to create the bump or the texture. That image you have above is a chore to create a bump map from. Sometimes all you can do is put your head down, grab a brush, and start working.

Comment: Ah, I was hoping for an easier solution, but thanks for your insight.

Comment: The thing is, both images are very different patterns. To turn one into the other isn't going to likely be doable.

Answer (score 1):

There’s only two ways I know to make a normal map — from a vector model or from a height map. Since you have a photo as a starting point, a height map is your best option.

You can probably fudge a decent height map by copying a channel and applying levels to it, because the dark areas are also the recessed areas.

[image]

From there, you’ll have to convert the height map to a normal map.

If you’re on a PC, NVIDIA have a Photoshop plugin available:
https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-texture-tools-adobe-photoshop

This tutorial seems good, but I can’t vouch for it’s accuracy:
http://www.moddb.com/groups/udk-developers-group/tutorials/ao-and-normal-maps-from-a-height-map

Or, you’ll have to use some other method (there are quite a few tools available for the task).